# SQL Server Update Column based on value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please assist if I should use a trigger or procedure. I am trying to update the `ScaleRating` in table `GSelfAssessment` from `GRatingScale` if the Score in `GSelfAssessment` falls between the minimum and maximum score in GRatingScale.

### GSelfAssessment table

[image]

### GRatingScale Table

[image]

Preferably this should be achieved for each row on either update or insert. I believe SQL trigger is the most appropriate one. I understand the inserted/deleted concept inside a trigger after my research. E.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_GSelfAssessment_update] ON [dbo].[GSelfAssessment]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE GSelfAssessment
    SET GSelfAssessment.ScaleRating= (Select )---this is where i have a problem-----
  END
```

I believe there is Guru out here who can give me solution to this. I will learn a lot.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Firstly, images of sample data often aren't helpful, other users can't interact with them, or copy the information out. Please edit your question to include the data as text, rather than an image. You've explained your goal here, however, it would be very helpful if you provided your expected output. Also, I'm not sure why you're using a trigger here, especially when the update is on the same table that is being updated. What is your reason for using a trigger?? If you want to update the existing values, a trigger won't help with that. What about an `INSERT` as well?

Comment: What value you want to use update in a scalerating column.

Comment: Thank you and this is noted to always use text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have that column.  Join to the rating table when you need to.  You can create a view if it makes it easier.

```
select … 
from GSelfAssessment  a
inner join 
GRatingScale  r 
on (a.Score>r.MinScore and a.Score<=r.MaxScore)
```

Adjust/create view as required

Comment: A view is great too. How do i know the rating based on minimum and max score. thats the query i am looking for. What i want is:  when a user input data into to the GSelfAssessment table they put a possible score which in recorded in the Score Column.  Automatically i should be able to calculate their rating based on the scale in my GratingScale table where i have minimum or maximum score. Its like the way you would when a student gets a score of A the grade is between 90-100 where 90 is minimum and 100 is maximum. Like a case scenarios. I don't know if this is clear.

Comment: @AnthonyWanyoike I've updated the answer to be more specific.

Comment: Yes. I get it and works fantastic. Thank you @loztinspace. truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server supports computed columns.  If you want `ScaleRating` to always be aligned with the rest of the data, then that is the best approach:

```
alter table GSelfAssessment
    add ScaleRating as ( . . . );
```

This adds a new "column" that gets calculated when the value is used in a query.  If the computation is expensive or you want to build an index, then use `persisted` so the value is actually stored with the rest of the data -- and recalculated when needed.

You can add the computed column in the `create table` statement as well.  If you have already created the table, you can drop the column and re-add it or modify it.

Comment: What i want is:  when a user input data into to the GSelfAssessment table they put a possible score which in recorded in the Score Column.  Automatically i should be able to calculate their rating based on the scale in my GratingScale table where i have minimum or maximum score. Its like the way you would when a student gets a score of A the grade is between 90-100 where 90 is minimum and 100 is maximum. Like a case scenarios. I don't know if this is clear.

Comment: @AnthonyWanyoike . . . "automatically" sounds like a computed column to me.